# How can i rotate object smooth without stop?

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

This is the script i'm using now:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour {



     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {


     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update ()
     {
         StartCoroutine(ContinuousRotation());
     }

     IEnumerator ContinuousRotation()
     {
         while (true)
         {
             transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 10);
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
         }
     }
 }
```

It's rotating the object but the problem is no matter what time i'm setting when running the game the rotating speed is the same. I tried: yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); then 5f in the original it was 0.01f but the speed never change.

Second problem is that the rotating making the object some flickering not flickering but some interruption to the eyes it's not really rotating smooth. Maybe the problem is the speed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than jumping through hoops to delay an event, use `Time.time` or `Time.deltaTime`

For example:

```
public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour {
    float timeSinceLastRotation;
    float timeUntilNextRotation = 0.01f; // 0.01 seconds

    void Update () {
        if (timeSinceLastRotation + timeUntilNextRotation > Time.time) {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 10);
            timeSinceLastRotation = Time.time
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is not the ideal way to handle a smooth rotation, as that will cause the object to snap to the next 10 degrees every 0.01 seconds. Rather, you should use `Time.deltaTime` which returns the time passed since the last frame.

That would look something like this:

```
public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour {
    float rotationMultiplier = 1.0f;

    void Update () {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationMultiplier);
    }
}
```

This would cause the object to rotate `1 degree per second * rotationMultiplier` increasing `rotationMultiplier` to `10.0f` can achieve a smooth 10 degrees per second.

**Edit -**

I'd like to add this modified excerpt from the Unity [Scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) regarding `Time.deltaTime`

> When you multiply with Time.deltaTime you essentially express: I want
>   to move this object 10 [degrees] per second instead of 10 [degrees] per
>   frame.